# Is my swap space being over used in OS X in /private/var/swap?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, memory, ssd, swap

I'm using Disk Inventory X to look at whats taking up the most disk space on my HD.

I understand that private/var/vm/ is where the OS stores items when it goes into hibernate.

I have 8GB of ram, but it seems to be using 58GB of disk space, with about 53 files.

Is that to be expected? It seems a bit high.

Context:

Macbook Pro - 750GB SATA - 8GB of RAM ( MAX)

Activity Monitor Shows 1.2GB of free System Memory

http://rightisleft.com/disk.png

http://rightisleft.com/free-memory.png

1. Im considering dropping in a smaller SSD drive and would like to know how to manage this better.
2. I run 3 separate user accounts, 1 for each company that i contract for.